# One class classification using Exclusively Positive Examples

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluations, one-class-classification

I have a dataset consisting only of the positive class, and I want to train a model to identify this data. Is it possible to use one-class classification models for this task? Additionally, how can I calculate accuracy, precision,recall... when there are no negative examples in the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) model or an [IsolationForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest) (read also [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#isolation-forest)). Basically, you feed them the data you have (regardless of the class label) and the model scores your data (according to an anomaly score defined by the author of the method): this if you use the `.score_samples(x)` method, otherwise the `.predict(x)` method returns you either $1$ or $-1$ label.

Indeed, to evaluate the trained model you should to collect at least a small validation set, in which there are both classes (inliers and outliers, or normal samples and anomalies) to compute the usual classification metrics.